# Django UnicodeEncodeError in errorlist

Tags: python, django, unicode

I am having an issue with rendering Django's ErrorList if one of my error list items is unicode. When Django renders my errorlist

```
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
```

[it runs the following code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.3.1/django/forms/util.py#L46):

```
class ErrorList(list, StrAndUnicode):
    """
    A collection of errors that knows how to display itself in various formats.
    """
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.as_ul()

    def as_ul(self):
        if not self: return u''
        return mark_safe(u'<ul class="errorlist">%s</ul>'
                % ''.join([u'<li>%s</li>' % conditional_escape(force_unicode(e)) for e in self]))
```

then in [`force_unicode`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.3.1/django/utils/encoding.py#L74):

```
s = unicode(str(s), encoding, errors)
```

and then translation in [`lazy`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.3.1/django/utils/functional.py#L209):

```
def __str_cast(self):
    return str(self.__func(*self.__args, **self.__kw))
```

The problem is that my string contains 'å' symbol and `str(u'å')` raises `UnicodeEncodeError`. Is there a good reason why `force_unicode` and `lazy` do not use `smart_str`? I have to do it myself and provide error messages as `str` objects instead of unicode to make it work.

So I get TemplateSyntaxError *Caught UnicodeEncodeError while rendering: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe5' in position 17: ordinal not in range(128)*. This seems telling that rendering my error list item (which is `u'å'`) caused the first UnicodeEncodeError having unicode message *'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe5'* and then second UnicodeEncodeError while rendering the message from the first one. Am I mistaken?

Django version: 1.3.1 (but this seems to happen in 1.4 as well)

Full traceback: https://raw.github.com/gist/2499077/ba60cb752acdb429dd6c2814ffb24272037a367a/UnicodeEncodeError.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can render `non_field_errors` (and the whole form) manually using insclusion tag or `{% include %}`. It is not direct solution, but it solves the problem and is more flexible anyway.

Comment: Thanks! It works fine with smart_str. I just want to know why I cannot use unicode in that case.